# Move a div overtop of elements hidden by visibility for printing?

Tags: html, css

I have a standard template I am using and I would like to make a panel of the my main viewable window printable with all other headers and menus hidden.  I have the following media specific css for printing which hides everything except the panel I want printed.

```
@media only print {
    * {
        visibility: hidden;
        margin:0;
        padding:0;
    }
    #printableArea {
        position: absolute;
        top:0;
        left: 0!important;
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
        z-index: 99999999;
        width: 100%;
    }
    #printableArea * {
        visibility: visible;
    }
}
```

I would like to move the #printableArea to the top left of the paper and have it expand the full width, however I've tried numerous things that hasn't changed it's position.  I can't seem to get it to go over top of the elements hidden using `visibility: hidden`.  Am I asking the impossible and if not, how do I achieve this with CSS?

Comment: Have you tried display: none instead of visibility: hidden? This will remove it from the flow completely

Comment: I have but you cannot display children or other descendants after you do it this way.  The div I am trying to print is not a direct descendant of *.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to cover your whole screen,
 `width:100%; height:100%;`
and if you are trying something else, I have know Idea.

Comment: Also, I really have not heard of visibility:hidden; 
I don't know try something like  display:none; 
Im sure you will figure it out

Comment: FYI: `visibility: hidden` pretty much does the same as `display: none`, it hides content from being viewed.  Content hidden by `visibility: hidden` is still rendered and the empty space it allocates onscreen is still visible, where `display: none` removes it from the page and the surrounding elements fill in the empty space.  Both are accessible via DOM manipulation.  However with: `display: none` I cannot make a specific child of elements hidden with that, visible.

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't provide any HTML I took a guess. This hides everything from the page except the specified id:

```css
 * {
   visibility: hidden;
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
 }
 
 p {
   background-color: lightblue;
 }

 #show {
   position: absolute;
   top: 0;
   left: 0 !important;
   margin: 0px;
   padding: 0px;
   z-index: 99999999;
   width: 100%;
 }

 #show * {
   visibility: visible;
 }
```

```html
<div>
  <p>Don't show</p>
  <p>Also don't show</p>
  <div id="show">
    <p>Show only me instead</p>
  </div>
</div>
```